# Microsoft Excel - Fuzzy Lookup Plugin

Tags: excel, ms-office, fuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

For anyone who has used the Fuzzy Lookup plugin -

In the case of multi-column fuzzy match, does it make a difference if I choose each column seperately in the "Match Columns" or together? What is the difference?

[image: Choosing all the columns together]

[image: Choosing the matching columns individually]

Comment: Do the similarity scores differ depending on which option you use? (All other settings being equal). You will at least have part of your answer.

Comment: Based on a short sample, it doesn't seem to differ. However, I'd like to be sure of the difference in both modes (if any). Might have subtle difference on large scale

Comment: I have been scanning documentation but haven't seen it referenced yet so it is an interesting question......Would be fairly easy to loop generate a large test dataset.

Comment: Yes, I am having a quality check review. However, it's a waste of time to understand a tool released by Microsoft given it's poorly documented.

Comment: We'll see what answers come up. Otherwise,  I would quite enjoy running some test cases tomorrow.